# How to get a result from a stored procedure as value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I had a similar question last week where I got good help so I'm trying again.

Basically I have this stored procedure where I input a string and get out an int from a table in the database. I would like to use this int for another stored procedure.

The problem is I don't know how to just get the actual value from my stored procedure result. If I wanted to I could show the output in a datagrid or something, but I don't want that. I just want the value in my program to be used for something else. How do I do this?

Here is the SP:

```
@EquipmentTypeDesignation NVARCHAR(50)

AS

SELECT EquipmentType.EquipmentTypeID
FROM EquipmentType
WHERE EquipmentTypeDesignation = @EquipmentTypeDesignation
```

I would like to just do something like this:

```
DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

...

var s = context.ReadEquipmentTypeDesignationSP("S9");
s.EquipmentTypeID somethingsomething something
```

I feel like I'm missing something basic here so thank you for your help.

Comment: I removed the [tag:wpf] tag since this question is not directly related to WPF, neither is it important for the answer.

Comment: Please describe what is `DataClasses1DataContext` and how do you access the database (ORM, ADO, etc).

Comment: I'm using Linq to SQL Class, but tbh I'm not entirely sure I can explain it very well.

Comment: it should work though, I can output the result from the SP into a datagrid and have it show perfectly. Am using ORM I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@EquipmentTypeDesignation NVARCHAR(50)

AS

DECLARE @equipTypeId int

SELECT top 1 @equipTypeId = EquipmentType.EquipmentTypeID
FROM EquipmentType
WHERE EquipmentTypeDesignation = @EquipmentTypeDesignation

RETURN @equipTypeId
```

in your code

```
var equipTypeId = context.ReadEquipmentTypeDesignationSP("S9").FirstOrDefault();
```